# Display progress with script running in paralel

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a bash script that runs in parallel inside a for loop, like this:

```sh
for (( n=0; n<${LIMIT}; n++ )); do
   my_function $n &
```

`my_function` is a function that runs in `LIMIT` virtual machines/nodes with ssh. It works fine, but i am not able to keep track of execution progress. It would be nice to have a progress bar or any other tool that can give a completion estimate. Unfortunately, all approaches i've searched doesn't apply to this parallel case.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to hack `pv` into this. Have each background process write a byte when it's done, tell pv how many bytes to call 100%, and there you are. If nobody else has answered yet I'll add an implementation when I get a break.

Comment: @Cyrus it's `bash`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you, sir!

Comment: BTW, I don't agree with the vote-to-close-as-a-recommendation-request, insofar as the question isn't "what tool can I us for X?", but "how can I accomplish X?", where not just tool selection but integration/use is part of the scope. Someone could already know that `pv` exists but not be able to successfully use it from their script; that's just as valid as describing how to use `jq` in a given context is, and questions of that type are common here.

Answer (score 4):

The below script uses the widely-packaged [3rd-party tool `pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) ("pipe viewer") to write a progress bar.

`pv` reads input from stdin and writes it to stdout -- but can write a progress bar (and optionally, an ETA and other statistics) to stderr in the process. It's most commonly used in situations like `curl | pv | tar`, but is perfectly suitable for this use case as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# version check: make sure automatic FD allocation is available
case $BASH_VERSION in
  ''|[1-3].*|4.[012].*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.3+ required" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

my_function() { sleep $(( 2 + (RANDOM % 10) )); } # replace with real function

# note "limit" is lowercase -- that's per POSIX guidelines
# see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html
limit=100 # as an example
pids=( )

# allocate a file descriptor that writes to a copy of "pv" -- "pipe viewer"
exec {pv_fd}> >(exec pv --progress --size "$limit" >/dev/null); pv_pid=$!

for (( n=0; n<limit; n++ )); do
  # every time my_function completes, write to the copy of pv
  (my_function "$n" {pv_fd}>&-; rc=$?; printf '\n' >&$pv_fd; exit "$rc") & pids[n]=$!
done

exec {pv_fd}>&- # now, close the process substitution feeding to pv

# pause here until all copies of my_function have completed
# by looping and passing each copy of wait only one PID, we can retrieve exact
# exit status for each copy.
for n in "${!pids[@]}"; do
  pid=${pids[$n]}
  wait "$pid" || echo "WARNING: Process $n (PID $pid) exited with status $?" >&2
done
wait "$pv_pid" # and wait for pv to exit

echo "Finished running all instances of my_function" >&2
```

Comment: I ran the script as is in "GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)", it reached 100% in 15 seconds, but didn't stop.

Comment: Your whole script written into "test.sh", then run "bash test.sh".

Comment: 100% sure. When I type Enter, it re-print "[============================================================================================>] 100%"    It seems `wait` waits for all subprocesses to finish, including `pv` process

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that -- works perfectly here (bash 4.4, pv 1.6.6).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238624/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-philippe).

Comment: Can you try with bash >= 5 ?

Comment: For folks reading the comment history: Bash 5.0 broke the initial version of this script insofar as `wait` waits for process substitutions, not only basic background commands. The current version requests exit status from each PID individually, and so does not have that issue.

Comment: In case you didn't see my last comment, seems the option `--stop-at-size` of `pv` can make your initial version work in Bash 5.0

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel you can do this:

```
export -f my_function
seq 0 ${LIMIT} |
  parallel -j${LIMIT} --bar my_function
```